# changing font color of data from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am new to MySQL an PHP and not sure how to do this.

I am displaying:

```
<?php echo "$cash"; ?>
```

on my page. Which works just fine.

What I would like to do is,
if it is a negative number I would like the number to be red
if it is a positive number I would like the number to be green
the font color that is.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
<?php $class = ($cash < 0) ? 'red' : 'green' ?>

<p class="<?php echo $class; ?>"> <?php echo $cash; ?> </p>

<style>
.red { color: red }
.green { color: green }
</style>
```

this works, but i would like the '$' to be included.
Example:

-$100
$100

Comment: So what attempts have you made?  Taking PHP/MySQL out of the equation do you know how to do this?  If so, then you just need to use PHP to dynamically modify the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
    .red { color: red }
    .green { color: green }
</style>

<?php if ($cash < 0): ?>   
    <p class="red">- &#36; <?php echo ($cash * -1); ?></p>
<?php else: ?>    
    <p class="green">&#36; <?php echo $cash; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you have a `UTF-8` document, you can write `$` instead of `&#36;`

Answer (score 2):

In a cleaner way :

```
<?php $class = ($cash < 0) ? 'red' : 'green' ?>

<p class="<?php echo $class; ?>"> <?php echo $cash; ?> </p>

<style>
.red { color: red }
.green { color: green }
</style>
```

`$cash` must be an integer for the condition to work properly. So in your MySQL you must only store in the cash column the actual value. A common practice is to store on another column the currency of the ammount you're storing. Or just hardcode it like :

`<p class="<?php echo $class; ?>"> $<?php echo $cash; ?> </p>`

Comment: This works great. Like I said prior I am new to this. Is there a way to display -$100 in red and $100 in green. Including the '$'. It seems that if i keep the '$' in my database, it shows green. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can just do an

```
echo $cash
```

You don't need to put it in quotes.

For your question, you can do this without mySQL.

```
<?php
    if($cash < 0) {
        echo '<font color="red">' . $cash . '</font>';
    } else {
        echo '<font color="green">' . $cash . '</font>';
    }
?>
```

One other way to do this without redundant font color tags is the following

```
<?php
    if($cash < 0) {
        $fontColor = 'red';
    } else {
        $fontColor = 'green';
    }

    echo '<font color="' . $fontColor . '">' . $cash . '</font>';
?>
```

If you want to be more up to date and avoid using the old school font tags, you can use css styles.

```
<?php
    if($cash < 0) {
        $fontColor = 'red';
    } else {
        $fontColor = 'green';
    }

    echo '<span style="color: ' . $fontColor . ';">' . $cash . '</span>';
?>
```

Edit: OR, you can do what sf_tristanb suggested.  As you can see there are a lot of different ways you can do this. :)

Comment: I had hoped that the font tag was as dead as IE4 and Netscape 4.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done much coding in PHP, and I'm having a tough time remembering how to get this to work if you want to apply the class to an entire table instead of for one specific DB column (I've tried substituting $cash with $row, but that doesn't call the 'IF' statement). Can you do this by 'Class' instead of 'Var', and simply assign the 'Class' to the entire table and/or specific table columns?